# Publish button missing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, publish, visual-studio-2022, publishing

I have an ASP.NET C# WebApi project in Visual Studio which I develop for some years now.

Suddenly, the Publish button is missing from the Build menu, so I cannot publish the changes I made.

I already uninstalled and installed again Visual Studio (with different options selected), updated to the last version, reset all settings in Tools > Import and Export Settings and applied General and Web development settings, nothing works.

I tried to install in another computer, and it is there. Tried to export the settings and import in the computer I need to use, and does not work.

Everything apart of this is working.

Do you have any clue what is causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I have the same issue.

Comment: No :( I'm using another computer for every time I need this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. In my case it was self inflicted.

My project file (.csproj) was missing the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` setting. When I copied one over from another similar project (that had the publish option) the issue was resolved and I could once again Publish from the context menu.

I seem to remember removing the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` entry to get over another Visual Studio issue that I was experiencing at the time :(

Comment: I know it works with some people. But unfortunately, not with me. In my case, it must be something else. I have the same values in both computers inside that tag :/

Comment: That's frustrating. I suppose you could double check the GUID meanings. There is a resource here: https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs For me once it was put to ASP NET 5 and C# it began working again.

Comment: I was able to fix it after formatting my laptop because of some other problems, and cloning the project from GitHub.

Comment: The list of guids has moved to here: https://github.com/JamesW75/visual-studio-project-type-guid